# How can I connect to Opensearch Serverless in java?

Tags: java, opensearch

I want to make a simple app that connects to Opensearch Serverless collection and only print information about it to see if it connects.

```
SdkHttpClient httpClient = ApacheHttpClient.builder().build();

        OpenSearchClient client = new OpenSearchClient(
                new AwsSdk2Transport(
                        httpClient,
                        "122345.us-east-2.aoss.amazonaws.com:443", // serverless collection endpoint
                        "aoss", // signing service name
                        Region.US_EAST_2, // signing service region
                        AwsSdk2TransportOptions.builder().build()
                )
        );

        InfoResponse info = client.info();
        System.out.println(info.version().distribution() + ": " + info.version().number());

        httpClient.close();
```

I get this error message `Request failed: [http_exception] server returned 404`. Here are the dependencies I used:

```
implementation("org.opensearch.client:opensearch-java:2.6.0")
    implementation("org.opensearch:opensearch:2.6.0")
    implementation ("org.opensearch.client:opensearch-rest-client:2.12.0")
    implementation("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.13'")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:opensearch:2.17.64")


    implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.17.290"))
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:s3")
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client")
```

I can't seem to figure it out why is not connecting, the endpoint is configured and it works fine in python or postman, but if I want to test it in java it does not work.